# Making a Turing machine, don't really understand the action table

Tags: c++, turing-machines

So this is the background for what I need, to do this problem.

> Implement a Turing machine that adheres to the following requirements. The state register should be declared as an `int`. The tape should be declared as a variable of a doubly-linked list type defined as a C++ class, where each node corresponds to one cell on the tape. The action table should be declared as a variable of an array-based list type defined as a C++ class, where each item corresponds to a struct consisting of five members corresponding to: (1) the current state, (2) the symbol read from the tape, (3) the next state, (4) the symbol to be written to the tape, and (5) the direction to move the read/write pointer, respectively. Each item in the action table corresponds to a “command” with the following format:
>
> (current state, symbol read) -> (next state, symbol to write) -> direction to next cell
>
> The current state and next state members should be of type `int`. The symbol read and symbol to write members should be of type `char`. The values of current state, symbol read, next state and symbol to write are problem dependent. The symbol B is a reserved symbol used to indicate that a cell is empty (i.e., blank). The direction to next cell member should be of type `char`, where L, - (i.e., the dash character), R, and H correspond to moving the read/write pointer to the left, no movement, moving to the right, and halting the computation (i.e., the problem is solved), respectively. Your C++ classes should be implementations of the doubly-linked list algorithms given on the CS210 Algorithms web page. Do not waste your time implementing any algorithms that you don't actually need.
>
> Prior to solving a problem using your Turing machine, the tape, state register, and action table must be initialized, and the read/write pointer must be positioned over a cell. To make your Turing machine capable of solving multiple problems, read the initial values from a text file containing data of the following format:
>
> ```
> initial_state_register_value 
> initial_tape_values
> first_row_of_action_table_values
> .  
> .  
> .  
> last_row_of_action_table_values
> -1 // action table terminator
> initial_read_write_pointer_position
> ```
>
> For example, a text file containing the following values will "program" your Turing machine to count to 16 in binary.
>
> ```
> 0 // initial state
> B 0 0 0 0 B // initial cell values on tape
> 0 0 0 0 R // move right
> 0 1 0 1 R // move right
> 0 B 1 B L // when a blank at the right is found, change to state 1 and move left
> 1 0 0 1 R // if a 0 is changed to 1, change to state 0 and move right
> 1 1 1 0 L // if a 1 is changed to 0, move left
> 1 B 0 1 H // if a B is changed to 1, stop
> -1 // end of action table
> 6 // initial position of read/write pointer
> ```
>
> Your program should print out the contents of the tape (and the position of the read/write pointer), from left to right: (1) after it is initialized, (2) after each intermediate computation (i.e., after an individual action is completed), and (3) after the computation halts. For example, the initial cell values on the tape and the initial position of the read/write pointer (represented by the character ^) would print as follows:
>
> ```
> B 0 0 0 0 B
>           ^
> ```

I've understood what the action table takes in as values.

What I'm having difficulty with now is trying to get just the first line read into an integer variable, the second line into the linked list class, the third to the '-1' line into the list by array class and the last line gets read in as an argument for a function that sets the pointer in the linked list.

Basically, my question is how can I get the end of a line and then set where that line is read to?

Most of what I know of reading from a file involves reading the entire file and then reading that to one variable.

Comment: The action table in the example starts with the line `0 0 0 0 R`, notice how you have all possible combinations for the first 2 columns: the table specifies the next state, symbol to write and the direction for each of the possible combinations of the first 2 columns, so all you have to do is lookup the right row using these columns as index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what the action table does and where it gets its rules from. I have a new question that I've edited into the main one.

Comment: Is your question really just "how do I read and parse lines of text from a file?"  That's a basic C++ question, so you should start with a basic C++ text or class before moving on to turing machines.

Comment: I'm really not getting a satisfactory answer from whatever sources I try to use, be it on the internet or otherwise.